# Convert to RGB returns a RGBA image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use Python and PIL to add some text to an image. I am failing on saving the resultant image as JPG.

I've based it on the example given on 
    https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def example():
    base = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('RGBA')
    txt = Image.new('RGBA', base.size, (255,255,255,0))
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Chalkduster.ttf', 40)
    drw = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
    drw.text((10,10), "HELLO", font=fnt, fill=(255,0,0,128))
    result= Image.alpha_composite(base, txt)
    result.convert('RGB')
    print ('mode after convert = %s'%result.mode)
    result.save('test1.jpg','JPEG')
example()
```

Running this prints `mode after convert = RGBA`
which is then followed by

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carl/miniconda3/envs/env0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 620, in _save
    rawmode = RAWMODE[im.mode]
KeyError: 'RGBA'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 14, in <module>
    example()
  File "example.py", line 12, in example
    result.save('test1.jpg','JPEG')
  File "/Users/carl/miniconda3/envs/env0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2007, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/Users/carl/miniconda3/envs/env0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 622, in _save
    raise IOError("cannot write mode %s as JPEG" % im.mode)
OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
```

The image is still RGBA after the convert to RGB function.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please give us your test.jpg. thanks

Comment: I am not quite sure, what are the motives of your code? Like you wanted to create partial opacity text, and then you are trying to save the output image in `RGB` color mode, which get's rid of the alpha channel of the image. Therefore, you lose all the opacity of your image after it's conversion to RGB.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S I just want to add some text onto a photo.

Comment: So, why partial opacity then? it's just an overlay of the image. You could have simply done that without the `composite()` function. As the link, that you provided in the question, is for partial opacity, wherethe output image will have text of different opacity in them, rather then text with no opacity at all.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S I chopped down my actual code to the smallest possible example to demonstrate my problem. Thanks for the info about the opacity.

Comment: Then I believe your code miserably fails, as if you want partial opacity in your code, then why are you converting the output file mode to `RGB`, because it get's rid of the alpha channel of the image, so in the end you lose all the opacity that you were trying to work on

Comment: @VasuDeo.S The code above is to demonstrate the problem. It is not my actual code. The answer provided by âńōŋŷXmoůŜ has resolved the issue I was having. Thank you for your input, I will take it on board.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed to assign the output to result. Change this code below

old:

```
result.convert('RGB')
```

new:

```
result = result.convert('RGB')
```